# insert rows data into a text maintaining data types

Tags: python, sql

I have this csv file `file_csv` I am reading from:

```
col1     col2     col3     col4     col5     col6     col7     col8     col9     col10
1        'bo'      'p'      5.5      "o"      8        "k"      8        "u"       10
...
1170 rows
```

I am trying to read from this file and insert these data rows into a text file to make a SQL INSERT command for table `t1`. For example, the first line in the text file (should have the same number of rows of the csv file) should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 'bo', 'p', 5.5, 'o', 8, 'k', 8,'u', 10);
...
1170 lines
```

This is the code I am developing so far:

```
import sys, os, random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

insert_file = open('insert_file_text.txt','w')
f = open("file_csv", 'r')

for line in f:
    items = line.rstrip("\n").split(";") 
    for item in items:
        item = item.replace("'", "''")#replace ' with '' for strings in postgreSQL
        insert_file.write(f"INSERT INTO t1 value(\'{item}\' ;\n")#this is the part I don't know how to go about it
insert_file .close()
```

The part I am not getting is how to aggregate all those items, in a compact pythonic way, into one string.

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you have a list of items you want to join into a string you can use the str.join method. e.g. if you have a list of strings, the str.join function could be helpful. e.g. if `a=[2,3,4]`, `", ".join(a)` will give you `"2, 3, 4"`.

In this case,

```py
for line in f:
    items = line.rstrip("\n").split(";") 
    item_str = ",".join([item.replace('"', "'") for item in items])
    insert_file.write(f"INSERT INTO t1 value({item_str});\n")
```

p.s. anytime that you are composing a string to send SQL commands, make sure you either 100% trust the source or are wary of [SQL injection attacks](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/SQL_Injection)

Comment: Thanks, but you got something like this: `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES('1, 'bo', 'p', 5.5, 'o', 8, 'k', 8,'u', 10);'` But that s not what I am interested in, I want the values to be of the same type as the original file, as I outlined above. I could have done what you did. I need something like this: `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 'bo', 'p', 5.5, 'o', 8, 'k', 8,'u', 10);` containing string and numeric values. Values were also one string! The replacement of " by ' ' was not there as well.

Comment: Are you saying 5.5 needs to be a float, 8, needs to be an int, etc.? Not sure I understand why because if you are saving the output to a text file it gets converted to a string anyway?

Comment: Yes, to a text file to be like this: `INSERT INTO t1 VALUES(1, 'bo', 'p', 5.5, 'o', 8, 'k', 8,'u', 10);` Basically two types: Numeric and String